# Switch Case Rendering Reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone.js app which on select change, changes the subview. The problem is, I'm basically duplicating a lot of code when all I'm changing is the product name.

I have a view that looks like:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    "change .changeType" : "changeHomeType"
},

render: function () {

    this.$el.append( render("homes/home") );
    var homeBlueView = new CityHomeBlueView({
        el: $('.home-view:last')
    });
    homeBlueView.render();

    return this;
},

changeHomeType: function (e) {
    var homeType = $(e.currentTarget).val();

    var thisHome = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".home");

    switch (homeType) {
        case "Blue":
            var homeBlueView = new CityHomeBlueView({
                el: thisHome.find( $('.home-view') )
            });

            homeBlueView.render();
            break;

        case "Red":
            var homeRedView = new CityHomeRedView({
                el: thisHome.find( $('.home-view') )
            });

            homeRedView.render();
            break;
```

And I continue to render subviews (for atleast 20 more), while all I'm changing is the color. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Change a class on the parent view and have CSS handle the color differences on the child view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two solutions.

**Solution1 : Create common child View.**  *recommended*

You can pass custom options to **Backbone.View**

```
 var homeRedView = new CityHomeView({    //create instance of common Child View
     el: thisHome.find( $('.home-view') ),
     color : 'red'  // or 'blue'
 });
```

You can use custom options by `this.options.color` in child View

**Solution2 : Use Class properties.**

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

  changeHomeType: function (e) {
      var homeType = $(e.currentTarget).val();

      var thisHome = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".home");

      var homeView = new this.constructor.ChildClasses[thisHome]({ 
         el: thisHome.find( $('.home-view') )
      }); 

      homeRedView.render();

   }

}, {
    ChildClasses : {         //Class properties
        red : CityHomeRedView,
        blue : CityHomeBlueView
    }
})
```

Comment: Backbone views haven't automatically set `this.options` for a long time, your first one needs an `initialize` to hook up `this.options`.